Examples of non-elliptic Doubly Periodic Functions
I'm reading something on elliptic functions and I do not understand why in various textbooks the authors do not give non-trivial examples of doubly periodic and elliptic functions. Indeed, they only introduce (after some work!) the function $\wp$ of Weierstrass and next show that it is doubly periodic function (actually elliptic since it is meromorphic).
Well, I'm trying to find other different examples (possibly with proofs) of:

A doubly periodic function that is not elliptic;

An elliptic function.



I think the point of not introducing any other elliptic function than $\wp$ because we have theorem  roughly saying that any elliptic functions can be expressed in term of $\wp$. See theorem 15.2 here: https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~hjrw2/RS%20lectures.pdf

When you ask for a doubly periodic function that is not elliptic, do you mean a doubly periodic function without poles? If so, then the only such things are constant functions. If $L$ is the lattice generated by the two periods, then the torus $\mathbb{C}/L$ is compact, so any holomorphic function $\mathbb{C}/L \to \mathbb{C}$ is bounded, and then composition with the (holomorphic) quotient map $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}/L$ gives a bounded entire function on $\mathbb{C}$, which is constant by Liouville's theorem.

Complex analysis is a very rigid subject: Given the values of functions on a countable complex set with a finite accumulation point, the function is fixed inside a circle of convergency around this point. In the rest of $\mathbb C$ the function can be  extended to all of  $\mathbb C$ by analytic continuation in overlapping circles of convergency,  or to a its complete Riemann surface in case of branching points.
So, as a consequence, given the function in an arbitrary small real intervall, the function is a fixed object in all of $\mathbb C$ or its Riemann surface.
It follows that fixing a periodic function in any of its real (quarter) period, the function is defined in all of $\mathbb C$.
By the fact, that complex rigid translations and rigid rotations of the argument map analytic functions to analytic function, the argument is valid for any complex line of periodicity.
Historically, the fields of the rational, the trigonometric, and later, the complex exponential functions yielded the foundation of the theory of complex analytic functions, defined at first as real functions with a complex argument by their series.
During the development of complex analysis, the first nontrivial field of functions, not fitting into this scheme, were the class of elliptic integrals evolving from line length of algebraic curves up to exponents of 4,
$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a_4 x^4+\dots +a_0\ }}$$
that can be somehow reduced to
$$ E(x,k)= \int_0^x \frac{d\xi}{\sqrt{(1-\xi^2)(1-k^2 \xi^2 )  }}$$
with in integrand with two double branch points at $\xi=\pm 1, \pm \frac{1}{k}$  on the real line for real $0\le k\le 1$
The complex inverse function of $w=E(z,k)\mapsto z= \text{am}(w,k) $ got the name 'Jacobi amplitude'.
Following the standard misuse of words and terms  by mathematicians, all functions involving the three new Jacobi functions $$\text{sn}(x,k)=\sin(\text{am}(x,k)),\quad \text{cn}(x,k)=\cos(\text{am}(x,k)), \quad \text{dn}(x,k)=\text{am}'(x,k)$$
got the name 'elliptic functions'.
$\text{sn, cn}$ are real periodic with a quarter period of the complete elliptic integral up to  point $$K(k)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{1-k^2 \sin^2(\phi)}}$$
This integral is a transform of the solution of the mathematical pendulum equation with Hamiltonian
$$H = \frac{d\phi^2}{2 dt^2} +(1- \cos \phi) $$
and equation of motion
$$dt^2 = \frac{d\phi^2}{1- k^2 \sin^2 \phi} $$
that transformes to the elliptic integrals as the function $t=\text{time}$ by $\phi = \text{angle }$ for a quarter period of the rotating pendulum.
So. by elementary analytical mechanics, the function $E(x,k)$ can be inverted like the integral $\arcsin$, its limit for $k\to 0$ or $\text{arctanh}$, its limit for $k\to 1$.
This wobbling rotation time in terms of the angle $\phi$ is called Jacobi amplitude $\text{am}(\phi,k)$, linear in time plus an oscillating modulation its derivative, the angular velocity $\omega(t) = \text{am}'(t,k)$.
From theory of harmonics in music the modulating parameter $k$ got its name 'modulus' that made an overwhelming carreer in modern mathematics.
By some elementary algebra in integral substitution, it's  easy to show, that all three Jacobi elliptic functions are periodic on the imaginary coordinate line, too, only the modulus is changed by $k^2 \to 1-k^2$.
Jacobi discarded his invention immediately, when he found that all of his elliptic functions and all their linear fractional transforms can be reorganized as quotients of Fourier series of a fixed period, the much more important Jacobi Theta functions.
By their parameter transform of modulus $k$, the elliptic nome $q$,  setting the deformatation from the pure sine, on gets the doubly periodic family of functions, that interpolates on the real line between harmonic functions and periodic Dirac $\delta$ combs.
In most books of complex analytic function all this highly interesting stuff (for physicists, see Klein-Sommerfeld Theory of the Spinning Top or the sine-Gordon field theory, for topologists the analytic deformation of periodic fields) is eliminated for the most simple representation of elliptic functions by the quotients of the two Weierstrass functions $\wp, \wp'$ that are defined by their invariants and have the most elementary pole lattice structure.
Somehow orthogonal to the standard, a nice exposition of all the aspects of elliptic functions see
Armitage, Eberlein, Elliptic Functions
Bottom line wrt. to the question: Any complex periodic analytic function has one or two complex periods, either transforms of exponentials with one direction of periodicity or of Jacobi  elliptic function with two complex independent directions forming a 2d-lattice of periodicity.
By th fact that all line integrals along the boundary of of a lattice cell is zero, the number of poles and zeros inside is always zero. It follows, that fixing the singular points inside a minimal lattice parallelogram is another form of the representation of a doubly periodic complex analytic function.
Higher periodicities do not exist.

Elliptic functions come from inverting elliptic integrals. In particular, when $0<k<1$ and
$$
w=\int_0^z{\mathrm dt\over\sqrt{1-t^2}\sqrt{1-k^2t^2}}.
$$
The inverse $z=\operatorname{sn}(w)$, after meromorphic continuation, can be shown to be doubly periodic
$$
\operatorname{sn}(w+4K)=\operatorname{sn}(w+2iK')=\operatorname{sn}(w),
$$
where $K$ and $K'$ are real numbers defined by
$$
K=\int_0^1{\mathrm dt\over\sqrt{1-t^2}\sqrt{1-k^2t^2}},
$$
$$
K'=\int_1^{1/k}{\mathrm dt\over\sqrt{t^2-1}\sqrt{1-k^2t^2}}.
$$
It is also shown that $\operatorname{sn}(w)$ has simple poles at $\pm iK'$. Consequently, elliptic functions are defined to be doubly periodic meromorphic functions. A use of Liouville's theorem indicates that nontrivial elliptic functions must possess at least two poles or a double pole in its fundamental periodic parallelogram.
For a derivation of the above result, see my blog article.
